# "Thread was being aborted" in ASP.NET when waiting for a response from a web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have an ASP.NET site that is calling a service. It can take the service several minutes to produce the response back in some cases and I am seeing the "Thread was being aborted" exception in those cases.

Is this related to a timeout setting somewhere? Can the timeout be increased?

**Update:**

Once I have increased the timeout as suggested by Brando Zhang, I am not seeing the "Thread was being aborted" exception, but the page itself is timing out for some reason. By "timing out" I mean that the page is not being refreshed with the contents of the response, once it arrives.

Now my `Web.config` has the following setting:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Update 2:**

Since the original problem outlined in the title is in fact resolved, I feel that the answer provided by Brando Zhang can be accepted as a valid answer to this question.

I will try to resolve the new issue mentioned in the first update by reducing the time it takes for the request to complete or by using long polling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to increase the executionTimeout property to avoid the thread aborted exception.

Details, you could refer to below config setting:

```
<configuration> <system.web>

<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" />

</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise. It did help me get rid of the exception, but now the page itself is timing out and is not being refreshed with contents from the response.

Comment: As far as I know, the browser has the default connection time out time, so you will face the timeout issue. Could you please tell me why your request takes so long time? If your request takes many time to process some thread, I suggest you could try to decouple the long running task from the asp.net and use either a service (wouldn't recommend it) or a scheduled task that polls for work to do. Then you could write an API or other interface to allow the client to check the work has done or not.

Comment: Thank you for advising about the timeout on the browser side and using long polling. This design was implemented before my time, so I don't have much information about the reasons why. :)